# Is it possible to avoid changes in my CSS, even from undesired * resets?

Tags: css

Think of a service that other webs integrate, this service, makes a popup appear on the web of who uses the service.

This `div` (window) has to keep its appearance intact.

It would be easy; `#popup #myid .myclass myelement {}`, `!important`, and voila.

But no, what happens, if a web uses bootstrap and resets styles that I do not contemplate?

It could protect and prevent the change of style, even if they add a style not common in a reset, for example

```
* {
   box-sizing: box-content;
}
```

Is it possible to prevent changes in my CSS, if I am part of many websites that could affect me?

Comment: No global styles will always affect the specificity of your styles. Generally you want everyone to namespace their css to their own content, however that doesn't always happen that way. The only thing you can do is lots of integration testing and being on the same page with the sites that use your content.

Comment: can you use an iframe in the popup?

Comment: The only way to *ensure* your styles are applied is to make sure they are loaded last using a scripting language like JavaScript, but then you run the risk of repainting the view that the user sees after page has started loading, which is considered bad practice. If your content is being loaded on someone else's website and it's important that your content maintain its style, then you surely must have some business agreement with whoever runs that website, and should put these terms in your contract.

Comment: What happens is that all the elements are not all existing styles added, many of them remain in their default values, and when someone arrives and applies a style to * and alters the default values of other elements, there is the problem, then the solution is to put in the waterfall, all the values even the default with the! important, so that it does not suffer external changes?

Comment: @imjared I can, how would it be?

Answer (score 1):

If you add something in-line and used !important, for example

```
<div style="box-sizing: box-content !important">
```

, it would be difficult for them to modify the style. However:

- Difficult is not the same as impossible, and
- This sort of design is **highly** discouraged.

I don't know what sort of service you're running, but asking users nicely not to modify your output may be a better solution.

Comment: but, the elements with default values?, and css resets (*)

Comment: @cesabal Inline styles with !important have priority over pretty much everything. There are still ways to overwrite them that *you cannot prevent short of an iframe*, but casual developers won't know how. Like my answer says, though, this is not good design.